# Semantic UI doesn't work at all

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, semantic-ui

I know I must missed something because none of the example of works in my computer.

Take the simplest first [example](http://semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown.html#/usage) at the website.

I copied the code AS IS and it doesn't work at all for me. I included the *semantic.min.css* and *semantic.min.js* also just in case I included the jQuery using google CDN.

Following is my **html** code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="semantic/dist/semantic.min.css">
<script src="semantic/dist/semantic.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>


<script>
$('.ui.dropdown')
  .dropdown()
;
</script>



<div class="ui dropdown">
  <input type="hidden" name="gender">
  <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
  <div class="default text">Gender</div>
  <div class="menu">
    <div class="item" data-value="male">Male</div>
    <div class="item" data-value="female">Female</div>
  </div>
</div>



</body>
</html>
```

The output is like this..
[image]

Thank you! I am pretty new to JavaScript and semantic UI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i use this order of linking js files and work fine

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../bower_components/semantic/dist/semantic.min.css">
  <script src="../bower_components/semantic/dist/semantic.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>


<select name="gender" class="ui dropdown" id="select">
  <option value="">Gender</option>
  <option value="male">Male</option>
  <option value="female">Female</option>
</select>


<script type="text/javascript">
  $('#select')
    .dropdown()
  ;
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have been having this problem as well, and this fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

I need to include jQuery before including .js and .css